# I'm only able to input one word into the file

Tags: c++, fstream

Like my title said, I am having problems with file input.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void CreateNewFile(const string FileName) {
    ofstream NewFile;
    string FileNamePlaceholder = FileName + ".txt";
    NewFile.open(FileNamePlaceholder);
    cout << "What would you like to write to the file? ";
    string InputForFile;
    cin >> InputForFile;
    NewFile << InputForFile;
    NewFile.close();
    cout << "You will now be able to view the file in your computer.\n";
}
void Start() {
    char NewFile;
    cout << "Would you like to create a new file? [Y/N] ";
    cin >> NewFile;
    if (NewFile == 'y' || NewFile == 'Y') {
        cout << "What would you like the new file to be named? ";
        string NewFileName;
        cin >> NewFileName;
        CreateNewFile(NewFileName);
    }
    else if (NewFile == 'n' || NewFile == 'N') {
        cout << "Ok, bye.\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "You did not type y, Y, n, or N!\n";
    }
}

int main(void) {
    Start();
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, I can only input one word at a time into the file.  I'm sorry if this is an obvious answer.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `>>` reads exactly one word. Look into `std::getline` and similar to get more than one word.

Comment: `getline` will fix this problem?

Comment: Depends. By default it will read everything up until you hit enter. If you want multiple lines, you'll have to make a loop. If you have more complicated parsing requirements, more complicated methods will be required.

Comment: One other note: Every time you open the file to write, you will overwrite the previous file. If you want to append to the file, you will have to open it diferently. See This for more: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open

Comment: Actually, this worked for me.  Thank you so much!  I used `getline(cin.ignore(),InputForFile);`

Comment: Do you want to put that into an answer so I could give you reputation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142213/discussion-between-nathanielsantley-and-user4581301).

Comment: Warning: `cin.ignore()` will always discard the first character it sees even if you don't want or need it to. If you know there is a preceding end of line character in the stream, remove it separately to avoid confusion. Try and stick to doing one thing at a time. It's easier to debug.

Comment: What would you suggest instead?